# How to create a dataframe with rows of open and close as columns

Tags: r

From this example of dataframe:

```
dframe <- data.frame(status = c("open","close","open","close"), name = c("Google","Google","Amazon","Amazon"), id = c(1,1,2,2), volume1 = c(2,3,1,2), othercol = c(5.3,1,3,7))
```

How is it possible to create a new dataframe with columns of open and close as columns? Here an expected output example:

```
data.frame(name = c("Google", "Amazon"), id = c(1,2), volume1_open = c(2,1), volume1_close = c(3,2), othercol_open = c(5.3,3), othercol_close = c(2,7))


> name id volume1_open volume1_close othercol_open othercol_close
>         Google  1            2             3           5.3              2
>         Amazon  2            1             2           3.0              7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you can use `dcast` in order to reshape your data to wide format:

**Code**

```
setDT(dframe)
dcast(dframe, name + id ~ status, value.var = c('volume1', 'othercol'))
```

**Result**

```
     name id volume1_close volume1_open othercol_close othercol_open
1: Amazon  2             2            1              7           3.0
2: Google  1             3            2              1           5.3
```